# StackOverflowError in 32 bit machine while loading a large ARXML file in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create and load an ARXML file using java SE 8 on a 32 bit machine.

```
ifile.create(inputStreamObj, true, null);
ModelLoadManager.INSTANCE.loadFile(ifile, false, null);
```

While loading the ARXML file, I am getting the below exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-05-11 14:36:03.520
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Loading Model Resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.InputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry.getInputStream(ZipBundleEntry.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticevent.DiagnosticeventFactory.<clinit>(DiagnosticeventFactory.java:41)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticevent.impl.DiagnosticeventPackageImpl.<init>(DiagnosticeventPackageImpl.java:1103)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticevent.impl.DiagnosticeventPackageImpl.init(DiagnosticeventPackageImpl.java:1157)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticevent.DiagnosticeventPackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticeventPackage.java:84)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticoperationcycle.impl.DiagnosticoperationcyclePackageImpl.init(DiagnosticoperationcyclePackageImpl.java:1342)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticoperationcycle.DiagnosticoperationcyclePackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticoperationcyclePackage.java:82)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticaging.impl.DiagnosticagingPackageImpl.init(DiagnosticagingPackageImpl.java:1323)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticaging.DiagnosticagingPackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticagingPackage.java:78)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnostictroublecode.impl.DiagnostictroublecodePackageImpl.init(DiagnostictroublecodePackageImpl.java:1453)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnostictroublecode.DiagnostictroublecodePackage.<clinit>(DiagnostictroublecodePackage.java:82)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticdebouncingalgorithm.impl.DiagnosticdebouncingalgorithmPackageImpl.init(DiagnosticdebouncingalgorithmPackageImpl.java:1331)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticdebouncingalgorithm.DiagnosticdebouncingalgorithmPackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticdebouncingalgorithmPackage.java:80)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticfreezeframe.impl.DiagnosticfreezeframePackageImpl.init(DiagnosticfreezeframePackageImpl.java:1338)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticfreezeframe.DiagnosticfreezeframePackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticfreezeframePackage.java:82)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticextendeddatarecord.impl.DiagnosticextendeddatarecordPackageImpl.init(DiagnosticextendeddatarecordPackageImpl.java:1329)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.dem.diagnosticextendeddatarecord.DiagnosticextendeddatarecordPackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticextendeddatarecordPackage.java:81)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.commondiagnostics.impl.CommondiagnosticsPackageImpl.init(CommondiagnosticsPackageImpl.java:1432)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.commondiagnostics.CommondiagnosticsPackage.<clinit>(CommondiagnosticsPackage.java:83)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.swmapping.impl.SwmappingPackageImpl.init(SwmappingPackageImpl.java:1317)
    at autosar40.diagnosticextract.swmapping.SwmappingPackage.<clinit>(SwmappingPackage.java:78)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.featuremodel.impl.FeaturemodelPackageImpl.init(FeaturemodelPackageImpl.java:1455)
    at autosar40.featuremodel.FeaturemodelPackage.<clinit>(FeaturemodelPackage.java:88)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.autosartoplevelstructure.impl.AutosartoplevelstructurePackageImpl.init(AutosartoplevelstructurePackageImpl.java:1324)
    at autosar40.autosartoplevelstructure.AutosartoplevelstructurePackage.<clinit>(AutosartoplevelstructurePackage.java:79)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.standardization.abstractblueprintstructure.impl.AbstractblueprintstructurePackageImpl.init(AbstractblueprintstructurePackageImpl.java:1371)
    at autosar40.standardization.abstractblueprintstructure.AbstractblueprintstructurePackage.<clinit>(AbstractblueprintstructurePackage.java:81)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
    at autosar40.standardization.clientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymapping.impl.ClientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymappingPackageImpl.init(ClientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymappingPackageImpl.java:1329)
    at autosar40.standardization.clientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymapping.ClientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymappingPackage.<clinit>(ClientserverinterfacetobswmoduleentrymappingPackage.java:80)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown
```

I tried with different `-xss` values like `320k`, `520k`, `600k`,`1024k`, `256k`, `1m`, `2m` and `10m` but no use.

My eclipse.ini file is as follows:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vmargs
-Xss1m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
```

The same code is working fine on a 64 bit machine through workspace, but on a 32 bit machine I am getting the issue. Can anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: Open your run configuration for Java application then in arguments tab there will be VM arguments text box , write -Xss1m , this will increase your stack size.

Comment: its working fine.

Comment: But i set the -xss1m in the eclipse.ini file but it didn't work

Comment: anyway thanks a lot Adya

Comment: Upvote the comment if you can

Comment: Clean up formatting

Comment: `-XX:+UseG1GC` is advised to have only on heaps > 4 GB, keep that in mind. Other GCs (parallel/cms) might be more preferable depending on your situation. But I bet parallel should be your go-to if you're unable to decide which one to use

Comment: Also, theoretically, max heap for the 32-bit JVM is 4G, doesn't matter how much ram he has. @Adya